# Operation is not valid due to current state of object while executing C# window service code

Tags: c#, oracle, exception

I have made a windows service in C# and while running the code, its giving the excpetion

> Operation not valid due to current state of object

on ExecuteNOnQuery line. I have used similar code before but haven't faced this issue.

```
public void CCP_to_WRM()
{
    DBConnection.Open_Connection();

    //Reading data from CCP Table in Gateway PC

    String sql = "select HEAT_NAME,STEEL_GRADE_ID,PRODUCTION,BILLET_STATUS,CASTER_NO from CCP_BILLET";
    DBConnection.ComndCCP.CommandText = sql;
    DBConnection.ComndCCP.ExecuteNonQuery(); //--> Exception occurs here.
    OracleDataReader ReadWRM = DBConnection.ComndCCP.ExecuteReader();

    while (ReadWRM.Read())
    {
        HeatId = ReadWRM[0].ToString().TrimEnd();
        StGr = ReadWRM[1].ToString().TrimEnd();
        BillN = int.Parse(ReadWRM[2].ToString().TrimEnd());
        BS = int.Parse(ReadWRM[3].ToString().TrimEnd());
        CsNo = int.Parse(ReadWRM[4].ToString().TrimEnd());


        //Inserting data from CCP into Mills DB
        int i = 0;
        int LayerNo = 0;
        int BilletId = 0;
        int BilletSeq = 0;
        int RowCount = 0;

        //string sqlD = "delete from stg_billet where heat_id='" + InHeat + "'";
        //DBConnection.ComndWRM.CommandText = sqlD;
        //DBConnection.ComndWRM.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string sql1 = "select layer_no from stg_bil_layer order by layer_no asc";
        DBConnection.ComndWRM.CommandText = sql1;
        DBConnection.ComndWRM.ExecuteNonQuery();
        OracleDataReader ReadLayer = DBConnection.ComndWRM.ExecuteReader();
        while (ReadLayer.Read())
        {
            LayerNo = int.Parse(ReadLayer[0].ToString().TrimEnd());
        }

        LayerNo++;
        //DialogResult result2 = MessageBox.Show("Inserting"+LayerNo);
        string sql2 = "insert into stg_bil_layer values ('1','BOX1'," + LayerNo + ",'SQUARE 150X150'," + BillN + "," + 0 + ",'"
                + StGr + "','" + HeatId + "'," + 2100 + "," + 12000 + "," + "'CASTER'," + "'CASTER'," + "'CASTER'," + "'$SNT',sysdate)";
        //to_date('"+DateTime.Now.ToString("DD/MM/YYYY")+"','DD/MM/YYYY')
        DBConnection.ComndWRM.CommandText = sql2;
        int RowS = DBConnection.ComndWRM.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (RowS >= 1)
        {
            //DialogResult result3 = MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted !!!!"+RowS);
            string sql3 = "select billet_id from stg_billet order by billet_id asc";
            DBConnection.ComndWRM.CommandText = sql3;
            DBConnection.ComndWRM.ExecuteNonQuery();
            OracleDataReader ReadBI = DBConnection.ComndWRM.ExecuteReader();
            while (ReadBI.Read())
            {
                BilletId = int.Parse(ReadBI[0].ToString().TrimEnd());
                //BilletSeq = int.Parse(ReadBI[1].ToString().TrimEnd());
            }

            sql3 = "select billet_seq from stg_billet order by billet_seq asc";
            DBConnection.ComndWRM.CommandText = sql3;
            DBConnection.ComndWRM.ExecuteNonQuery();
            OracleDataReader ReadBS = DBConnection.ComndWRM.ExecuteReader();
            while (ReadBS.Read())
            {
                //BilletId = int.Parse(ReadBI[0].ToString().TrimEnd());
                BilletSeq = int.Parse(ReadBS[0].ToString().TrimEnd());
            }
            //DialogResult result4 = MessageBox.Show("Bilet ID " + BilletId+'\n'+"Billet Sequence "+BilletSeq);

            for (i = 0; i < BillN; i++)
            {
                //DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("Inside Loop");
                BilletId++;
                BilletSeq++;
                string sql4 = "insert into stg_billet values (" + BilletId + "," + BilletSeq + ","
                + 1 + ",'BOX1'," + LayerNo + "," + CsNo + ","
                + 1 + ",'" + HeatId + "'," + "'PLAN' " + ",'" + StGr + "'," + "'1234567890',"
                + 0 + ",sysdate,sysdate," + 0 + "," + 3 + "," + 1 + "," + 150 + "," + 150 + "," + 12000 + "," + 2100 + ","
                + 3 + "," + 1 + "," + 10 + "," + "'$SNT',sysdate)";

                DBConnection.ComndWRM.CommandText = sql4;
                int RowB = DBConnection.ComndWRM.ExecuteNonQuery();
                RowCount = RowCount + RowB;

            }

            /*
            if (RowCount >= 1)
            {
                DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted !!!!" + '\n' + RowCount + " Billets");
            }
            DBConnection.Close_Connection();
            this.Hide();
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.ShowDialog();
            */
        }

        /*
        else
        {
            DialogResult result4 = MessageBox.Show("Failed to Insert !!!!" + RowS);
            DBConnection.Close_Connection();
            this.Hide();
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.ShowDialog();
        }
        */
    }
    DBConnection.Close_Connection();
}
```

I have used a DBConnection class for making connection to the database(DBConnection).
I have even tried making connection in the same script but it didn't work.

[image: Error message]

Comment: So what does `DBConnection.Open_Connection`? You need to show us the relevant code. Everything after the exception is completely superfluous to this question.

Comment: DBConnection.open_connection() is a function i have defined in a different class for connection. There's also a different function to close it i.e. close_connection(). I have used this BBConnection.open_connection function in other codes also but it has never created any problem.

Comment: Well it's clearly a problem now, we cannot help you otherwise.